# Minimum number and average number using for loop and not for each loop

Tags: for-loop

I want to print out the minimum number and average number for the given list of numbers by using for loop and not for each loop? I tried but its not working may be I am doing error somewhere or I am failing to understand the concept...?? Any help will be appreciated...

```js
public class MaxMin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};


        // Print all the array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myList[i] + " ");
        }

        // Summing all elements
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
            total += myList[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Total is " + total);

        // Finding the largest element
        double max = myList[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++) {
            if (myList[i] > max) max = myList[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Max is " + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tag your question with a language: i.e. Java.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to whats not working, also tag your question with programming language and maybe bugfix. Also, you say you want to print out the "minimum" number but in your code it looks like you want the max?

Comment: Also, you have a `for` loop to find max. Why can't you modify that to find min as well? You have `total` so you can calculate average from that. Please try to expand your question beyond "but its not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minimum:

```
// Finding the min element
double min = myList[0];
for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if (myList[i] < min) {
      min = myList[i];
    }
}
```

To find the average you already have the sum so:

```
// find average:
double avg = total/myList.length;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... Really appreciate your help :-)